# Stop Html.Action from being called on Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have below `div` inside a parent view and the below `Html.Action` returns a `PartialView`

```
<div id="preview" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        @Html.Action("GetPrintView", "Connector")
    </div>
</div>
```

I open the above `modal` using below jquery:

```
$("#printdoc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#preview');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
});
```

The issue is, whenever the parent `.cshtml` is loaded it calls the above `Html.Action`, but this should be only called when clicked on button. I tried using `data-url` for the `div` but still the action is being called repeatedly. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Action` will execute the action when view is loaded. Since you don't want this, You need load data asynchronously.

You can store URL in custom `data-*` attribute to generate the URL use `Url.Action`. On click of the button load the partial view using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

*HTML*

```
<div class="modal-content" data-url='@Url.Action("GetPrintView", "Connector")'>        
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$("#printdoc").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var modal = $("#preview .modal-content"); //Find the element
    $(modal).load(modal.data('url')); //Fetch url and load partial view

    $(this).attr('data-target', '#preview');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
});
```

Comment: That is what I tried already, but it calls the partial view action method on load of parent page.

Comment: @Saroj, This will not call partial view action as we are not calling it anywhere unless `printdoc` button is clicked. Did you used `Url.Action`?

Comment: That action method is nowhere called except `printdoc` click. Still that method is getting called. I don't know how to attach the image in comment, else I could have shown you the call stack. Is the action method missing any `attributes`?

Comment: I found the issue, that was still using `Html.Action` instead of `Url.Action` ... :) . Issue resolved now.. Thanks a lot.